# How to choose the correct way for indexing a series of databases?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm building a database with tables that relate to each other, the problem is that the indexing method that I used seems to have made certain mistakes because some indexes refer to different rows between the tables.

I have a dataset of genetical markers with 1'405.301 (SNPs) rows and 3092 columns (Genotypes), each SNP is identified by the chromosome, the position inside them and the alternative alleles that has the SNP.

I've tried to upload the whole dataset into a table but it exceeded the max column limit of a table in psql so I split the dataset in a series of subsets. Each subset had certain columns and some others that helps me to identify each row (SNP). So I wrote a python sqlachemy script that creates an empty table with the same columns names of the correspondent subset of the dataset. After that I used the psql command COPY for dump each subset for the correspondent table and for each table I created an autoincrement index as a primary key.

The problem comes when I made comparisons between data of different tables because the index refers to different rows between the tables

This is the psql code for dump the subset and set the index of each table

```sql
COPY p11 FROM '/home/pybonacci/Documentos/.../p11.csv' WITH (HEADER true, format csv, DELIMITER E'\t');

ALTER TABLE p11
  ADD COLUMN marker_id serial primary key;
```

and I realized that the indexing problem occurs in certain parts of the table with this code

```sql
select 
    p11.marker_id, p11."ALT", p11."POS", p08.marker_id, p08."ALT", p08."POS" 
from 
    p11 
inner join 
    p08 on p08.marker_id = p11.marker_id
where 
    p11.marker_id > 1710
order by 
    p11.marker_id
limit 100
```

Output:

```
p11.marker_id    p11.ALT    p11.POS    p08.marker_id    p08.ALT    p08.POS
1716             T          390961     1716             T          390961
1717             G          390963     1717             G          390963
1718             A          390969     1718             A          390969
1719             T          392223     1719             AG         391838
1720             CT         392240     1720             T          391847
1721             AG         391838     1721             A          391864
1722             T          391847     1722             G          391876
1723             A          391864     1723             A          391881
```

I expected that an empty output for this query.

I hope to be clear, I'm so sorry for my bad English

Comment: Could you show us your schema, please?

Comment: So those 3092 columns are actually triplets that consist of `(chromosome, alt, pos)`?

Comment: Hi@Schwern the schema of my DB is simple, just 36 different tables each with the same first five columns ( marker_id, Chromosome, Pos, Alt and Ref) and and the next 96 columns are for each sample. The problem is with marker_id that isn't synchronized accross all the tables. @a_horse_with_no_name these columns are the identifiers of each SNP(row) and the next columns are the samples.  DB schema: https://imgur.com/N89u8ou

Answer (score 0):

While not impossible, synchronizing the auto generated `serial` values across tables is probably going to be a challenge.

I would approach this in a different way.

The maximum number of columns in a table is hard limit that you can't really get rid of. Additionally that limit also applies to the number of columns a single query can return. So even if you split up the dataset into many tables, you can't access all SNPs in the same query because joining all tables would return a result that exceeds the maximum number of columns.

So you need to find a different way to store this.

Unless you can completely change the structure of the input file, I would import that file into a table that has a single column and then split up the data using Postgres string and array functions.

First load the raw file into a table that only contains one `text` column.

```
create unlogged table import_table
(
  line text
);
```

When importing the file, you need to use a character as the delimiter that will not occur in the input file so that `copy` treats everything as a single line:

```
copy import_table from '....' WITH (HEADER true, format text, DELIMITER '§');
```

I don't know if `§` can occur in the data or not - you will need to find an appropriate character. A non-printable character might work as well, e.g.: `e'\x01'`

Once the data is in there, you can convert the line to an array (using `string_to_array()`) and access each element (column) individually, e.g. to insert the rows into the first "subset" table:

```sql
insert into p01 (marker_id, alt_1, pos_1, chromosom_1, alt_2, pos_2, chromosom_2, ...)
select c[1]::int as marker_id, 
       c[2] as alt_1, 
       c[3] as pos_1, 
       c[4] as chromosom_1, 
       c[5] as alt_2, 
       c[6] as pos_2, 
       c[7] as chromosom_2, 
       ....
from (
   select string_to_array(line, E'\t') as c
   from import_table
) t;
```

And similarly for the other "subset talbes". This could be automated using a PL/pgSQL procedure if needed.

But again: you can not join all those tables together to get a single result on everything as that again would exceed the maximum number of columns.

Depending on how you need to access the data later, there are other options to keep all rows in a single table.

One solution would be to create a custom type `snp_type` that contains three fields, then create a table with 1000 columns of that type:

```
create type snp_type as
(
  alt text, 
  pos integer,
  chromosome text
);

create table data
( 
  marker_id integer, 
  snp_1 snp_type, 
  snp_2 snp_type, 
  snp_3 snp_type,
  ...
);
```

Then use something like the following to populate that table from the import table:

```sql
insert into p01 (marker_id, snp_1, snp_2, ...)
select c[1]::int as marker_id, 
       (c[2], c[3]::int, c[4])::snp_type as snp_1,
       (c[5], c[6]::int, c[7])::snp_type as snp_2,
       (c[8], c[9]::int, c[10])::snp_type as snp_3,
       ....
from (
   select string_to_array(line, E'\t') as c
   from import_table
) t;
```

Again, this could be automated using PL/pgSQL.

Once you have that `snp_type` you could also think about storing all those values into a single column that is an array of that type:

```
create type snp_type as
(
  alt text, 
  pos integer,
  chromosome text
);
create table data
( 
  marker_id integer, 
  snps snp_type[]
);
```

The insert would then look something like this:

```sql
insert into p01 (marker_id, snp_1, snp_2, ...)
select c[1]::int as marker_id, 
       array
       [
          (c[2], c[3]::int, c[4])::snp_type,
          (c[5], c[6]::int, c[7])::snp_type,
          (c[8], c[9]::int, c[10])::snp_type,
          ....
       ]
from (
   select string_to_array(line, E'\t') as c
   from import_table
) t;
```

This could also be automated using PL/pgSQL

---

All the code above is just a rough sketch, there might be errors in them. The idea is to give you you a starting point and ideas on what you can do.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name many thanks for your reply. I really don't need access to all the columns at the same time, I need to take just certain columns for make comparisions between them (maximum in 3 different tables) but I tried to join this  tables based in the serial index and I realized that the indexing method made mistakes so I don't know if is possible mantain the same tables but with a synchronized index accross all the tables. I don't know if could be a good idea create bigger tables with the same type of indexing because it failed before to synchronize my rows accross the tables.